# TV episode where man enters forbidden door, finds world with its own forbidden door

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm remembering an anthology TV series that I probably watched sometime in the mid to late 90's (though I wouldn't exclude the early 2000's) in America (English), and it was most likely intended for children or young adults.

The setting is somewhat ancient, like a story you might imagine from the Old Testament in the Bible. From what I remember, a young man lives in a place with a forbidden door that his father(?) tells him he should never enter because there's no way back. For some reason (curiosity? discontent?), he decides one day to go through it and ends up walking down a long dark tunnel. There may have been some giant or man in the tunnel he has to get around, but I could be remembering that part wrong. Afterwards I'm pretty sure he wakes up in a desert, where he's rescued by some travelers who bring him to a place where he is well cared for, and generally the world seems to be better than his previous life.

This place has a forbidden door of its own though, and given how well it turned out last time, he goes through again. This time, however, he's not so fortunate. I think he wakes up in a desert again, but overall the world is less welcoming. He may or may not go through this world's door again, but the outcome is never good.

The story essentially has a moral attached to it of appreciating what you have because trying to go for more means you could end up losing it all.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4720856/

Comment: @JohnP That's exactly it. Throw it up as an answer and I'll accept. I searched for forbidden door, but with enough extra details that it seems it got filtered out. Thank you =)

Comment: Done. Lucky find, I've never seen it. I did find a link to the entire episode, however.

Comment: @JohnP I'm usually pretty good at finding things, but this one had alluded me for some time now, and your Google-fu is clearly superior ;) I guess I just assumed "forbidden door" would be too vague. I found it on youtube after your comment and checked to be sure, and it's definitely the right one.

Comment: Cool. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The episode you are looking for is part of the British TV series "[Storybook International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storybook_International)", titled "The Forbidden Door".

Unfortunately, the only synopsis I can find is the blurb on IMDB:

> A penniless boy is taken in my his rich Uncle and his crying friends, but can not resist opening the the forbidden door.

However. [this site](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3l3rvl) appears to contain a full video of it. (One also available on youtube).